# Google Analytics code is not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

This Google Analytics code is not working. I cannot see any visitors, and events are not triggered. Any ideas? THANKS.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="2;URL=http://www.example.com"> -->
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-99999999-1']); // Hidden my real one
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
        (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();

</script>
</head>


<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'My Event', 'Hypothesis', 'Email', 1]);

window.location = "http://www.example.com";

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you have just put it in, it will take some time to appear.
Also, do check for errors in error console of Firefox/Chrome and put them here if you find them

Comment: Even with the "Real time" functionality?

Comment: not sure if it starts giving real time right away but according to   http://smallbusinessshift.com/guides/google-analytics/
"it takes some time for Google Analytics to start receiving data.".. so may be you should wait a while or check for other js errors

Comment: Because you're using the asynchronous analytics code, when you set window.location, you're probably leaving the page before any of the commands in _gaq have been processed. See my answer for code that sets window.location via _gaq commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analytics code takes about 2-3 hours to show on Analytics, and even longer if its the first time. Wait for the delay and I bet it will come up :)

Answer (score 1):

Normally Analytics takes some time to get the first measurements. You can test your tracking code with the [GADebug extension for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna) however. It will display information about your setup and triggered events in the Chrome console.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics records data by making tracking pixel requests from the analytics servers.
If you're loading another page (by setting `window.location` in your code) before the tracking pixel requests have completed, you risk getting incomplete or no data. Also, because you're using asynchronous tracking, it's possible you're leaving the page before any `_gaq` requests have been processed.

The following code set's window.location via a _gaq command (making sure that analytics code has loaded and other commands have been processed), and delays 150ms (to allow the tracking pixels requests to complete).

```
_gaq.push(function() {
  setTimeout(function(){ window.location = "http://www.example.com"}, 150);
});
```